# Trying to import shapefile using RGeo Ruby gem, getting Stack Level too deep

Tags: ruby, postgis, rgeo

I don't know whether this is some interaction inside my code, or perhaps naming conventions inside the shapefiles I'm using, but the following code results in a `Stack level too deep` message

```
def read_shapefile
  @shp_path = Dir[File.join( @tmp_path, '*.shp') ].first

  srs_database = RGeo::CoordSys::SRSDatabase::ActiveRecordTable.new

  factory = RGeo::Geos.factory(:srs_database => srs_database, :srid => 96805)
  #factory = RGeo::Geos::CAPIFactory.new
  cartesian_preferred_factory = LandUnit.rgeo_factory_for_column(:location)


  RGeo::Shapefile::Reader.open(@shp_path, factory: factory) do |file|
    file.each do |record|
      cartesian_cast = RGeo::Feature.cast(
          record.geometry, factory: cartesian_preferred_factory, project: true)

      cartesian_cast.each do |poly|
          lu = LandUnit.new
          lu.guid = record.attributes[@params['guid']].to_s
          lu.country_code =  @params['country_code']
          lu.location = poly    
          # error happens here!
          lu.save
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Migrations for model:

```
class CreateLandUnits < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :land_units do |t|
      t.string :country_code, null: false, index: true
      t.string :guid, index: true
      t.geometry :location, srid: 3785

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Relevant part of schema.rb:

```
  create_table "land_units", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "country_code",                                          null: false
    t.string   "guid"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.spatial  "location",     limit: {:srid=>3785, :type=>"geometry"}
  end

  add_index "land_units", ["location"], :name => "index_land_units_on_location", :spatial => true
```

Backtrace points to `active_record/transactions.rb`, line 286:

```
def rollback_active_record_state!
  remember_transaction_record_state
  yield
rescue Exception
  restore_transaction_record_state
  raise    # HERE<<<
ensure
  clear_transaction_record_state
end
```

Tried everything.  Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:  In case anyone is wondering about those parameters, on the failed call they resolve to guid: '6020048.00', and country_code: 'ca'.

I should also add, that the log shows this:

```
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "land_units" ("country_code", "created_at", "guid", "location", "updated_at") 
  VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["country_code", "ca"], ["created_at", "2015-03-23 20:59:38.771649"], ["guid", "6020048.00"], 
  ["location", "002000000300000ec90000000100000028c164b311c749d0be4049101977159301c164b311c7508b1140491022249508cfc164b311c7671af24049103f70c23377c164b311c785400940491065d156a4f5c164b311c78493be40491082fd398873c164b311c783e2024049109c841e4650c164b311c78327ba404910ae43343896c164b311c7810e65404910b976a8c3dfc164b311c77c6113404910cf2943e8c7c164b311c777d3ba404910e3e11b1b56c164b311c771ff68404910fdcea7cc13c164b311c7716ef74049110061ae5237c164b311c76d520940491113afcec9eec164b311c7631bad4049114313691234c164b311c75f336f40491154764b6b38c164b311c75249bb40491140bebb55fac164b311c749492e40491135844d8b3fc164b311c740bbbb4049112ae8b30272c164b311c737d9274049111f6444e7acc164b311c72f4d334049111430f7e5f3c164b311c726871640491108fa115ffac164b311c71e34d2404910fe160b0597c164b311c7151806404910f28d86b4f4c164b311c70ca8b0404910e7a793a963c164b311c705b232404910deb9fc574ac164b311c703a91d404910dc20d4806ac164b311c6fb1d64404910d0ed325688c164b311c6f290ef404910c605069167c164b311c6e9e83a404910bacf71a130c164b311c6e0cba9404910af46584a4fc164b311c6f115694049105a80074a79c164b311c6f69ca64049103bc8277f0fc164b311c6facd224049102626e4a97cc164b311c6fec1f340491011192ee217c164b311c703ca8a40490ff67dac4e4ac164b311c707dc6d40490fe171e94d20c164b311c70c6bce40490fc98cc82ecdc164b311c720cc5340490fe45c78305ac164b311c73527f340490ffe8cde5378c164b311c749d0be4049101977159301"], ["updated_at", "2015-03-23 20:59:38.771649"
  ]]
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
```

The SQL it shows executes just fine in the console!  That's the crazy bit.  This suggests to me that that the problem is some before_save method, but I haven't defined any.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the stack trace itself, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have this figured out. This spatial reference code, "96805", doesn't have any entries at spatialreference.org. I'm not saying it doesn't exist, but its probably referenced under some other srid.

You can track it down though, I imagine it exists but is referenced using some other code. Oftentimes the same proj4 code is referenced under multiple SRID references. Anyway, for one of your shapefile sets for this mysteriously projected file, open the `*.prj` file in a text editor. That will show you your `proj4` code. You can deal with this multiple ways from here. One thing is you can copy this proj4 code into google and try to get the official srid for it then go from there.

Alternatively, you can directly utilize the proj4 code to recast the geometry without any official srid.